Can "having done" serve as a gerund?
Is the sentence "Having done the homework enables him to play freely." grammatical? I'm quite confused.My teacher said that "having done" can not be used as a gerund.But I search online, and find some people said it can be used as a gerund.The original question is ". While being questioned on the court, the man denied  ____  the old lady’s necklace.
A. having taken  B. taking C. to have taken D. to take
"

I've answered, but please [edit] your question to explain why you are confused.  What does your text book say about gerunds?  Why do you think this is doubtful?

I suggest talking more with your teacher (they are paid to answer your questions!)

My teacher still sticks to his opinion.But I think he is wrong..

You "original" question is unrelated to the example about homework. The missing words are not the subject of a clause.

I find the bare gerund (i.e. without his or him) marginal at best: *Having done his best made him feel proud.  vs. His having done his best made him feel proud.

In Stealing the old lady’s necklace was a crime, the first word ("Stealing") is a gerund, and the first five words ("Stealing the old lady's necklace") form a gerund phrase. Personally, I don't find Having stolen the old lady’s necklace was a crime idiomatically acceptable.

Unlike stealing, having in "having done" is not a lexical verb but an auxiliary.  Is this grammatical: Having eaten some old fish made him feel ill.

@TimR: Neither having stolen [X] nor having eaten [X] strike me as credible "gerunds" to be used as subject nouns.

@FumbleFingers Same here. But "His having eaten some old fish made him feel ill" sounds OK enough.   *Having stolen the jewelry got him two years in prison.

Thank you. I understand.

Clarification: Perfect Participle vs. Gerund and Tense Consistency.
As per the grammar we learned (and in agreement with your teacher and the British Council website), here are the key points to address your doubts:
1. Perfect Participle and Gerund.
The phrase  "having done" is a perfect participle, while  "doing" is a present participle.
Perfect Participle:.

In sentences like  "Having done his homework, he went to play," "having done" functions as a perfect participle, not a gerund.
A perfect participle typically acts as an adjective or adverb, providing extra information about the verb or action in the sentence.
In this case, "having done" emphasizes that the homework was completed before he went to play.

Gerund:.
A gerund is a verb form ending in "-ing" that functions as a noun.
Examples include "eating," "running," or "studying."
Gerunds can act as the subject, object, or complement in a sentence.
This distinction is key: while perfect participles modify or describe actions, gerund perform the role of nouns.
2. Tense Consistency:.
The sentence "Having done the homework enables him to play freely" is not grammatically correct because of a mismatch in tenses.
The  perfect participle phrase  "having done" implies a completed action in the past.
The verb "enables" is in the simple present tense, which refers to general or habitual truths.
This mixing of tenses creates inconsistency because the action of completing the homework (past) doesn’t align naturally with the habitual tone of "enables."
Suggested Rewrite:.
To correct the sentence, you could use:
First Conditional: "If he finishes his homework, he can play freely.".

This maintains logical and tense consistency, clearly expressing the relationship between completing the homework and playing freely.

3. Perfect Participle Clauses:.

Perfect participle clauses  show that the action they describe was finished before the action in the main clause. Perfect participles can be structured to make an active or passive meaning.
Having got dressed, he slowly went downstairs..
Having finished their training, they will be fully qualified doctors..
Having been made redundant, she started looking for a new job.

Source: British Council

A participle/gerund is any verb with the -ing ending.  So "having" is a participle/gerund.  Modern grammars don't distinguish between participles and gerunds. The phrase "having done the homework" can be the subject of a sentence. It is correct grammar.
But this is not how a native speaker would normally express this idea.  It would be much better to use two clauses linked with a conjunction.  "He has done his homework, so he can play freely." for example.

Thank you. So "having done" can be used as a noun, right?

Nouns are used in lots of ways.  so "as a noun" is rather meaningless.  It can be the subject of a sentence.  But as I explain above, don't do that.  It is not how to express this idea.

The example above is just a hasty example. I just want to ensure that "having done"can be used as a subject.

The  original question is the following: . While being questioned on the court, the man denied  ____  the old lady’s necklace.
A. having taken  B. taking C. to have taken D. to take

"questioned in court" surely, not "on the court"  (unless this at a tennis match)  A or B are both -ing verb phrases, and are both correct responses.  This is completely unrelated to the use of an -ing verb as the subject of a clause.  THe subject of in this case is "the man"

@Martin Be sure when using such constructions that you make clear who the actor is. Otherwise you get nonsensical constructions such as: Having robbed the shop, the policeman arrested the thief.
